# Refresh Rails view in realtime

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, real-time

I have a Rails 3.2.14 legacy app where I have a view that I'd like to refresh the partials in without page reload.  I currently have this working, but am wanting to see if this is the best way to go about it.

Here are come code excerpts:

index.html.erb:

```
<div id="active">
  <%= render "assigned_calls" %>
</div>

<div id="inactive">
  <%= render "unassigned_calls" %>
</div>


<script>
  $(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
      $.getScript("/calls").fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
        window.location = "/users/sign_in?duplicate_session=true";
      });
    }, 10000);
  });
</script>
```

index.js.erb

```
$("#active").html("<%= escape_javascript render("assigned_calls") %>");
$("#inactive").html("<%= escape_javascript render("unassigned_calls") %>");
```

So far I have a JS call to get /calls every 10 seconds.  This works fine but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.  In the view we have a timer (evaluates date of call versus Time.zone.now) and it updates ever 10 seconds since the partials reload.  I'd really like this to be truly realtime and wondering if setting the interval in the JS to 1 second would be advised.  This seems like an awful lot of partial refreshes and tons of queries/log entries.

If there's a better way to refresh the divs in realtime, I'm all ears.  Right now what I have works, but my ultimate goal is to get the data to update in realtime somehow.

Comment: There's a nice article about Rails and real-time updates using WebSockets and a JS framework here (with alternatives): http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/02/27/adding-real-time-to-a-restful-rails-app/

Comment: Just some wild ideas: [HTML5 server send events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) ? Or [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) ? Depending your app this might be more work than expected though.

Comment: @MarcoCI I was actually looking into this same article last night. I'm not sure if I want to go to all this trouble as I'm eventually re-writing the application in Rails 4.x.x and I believe it supports realtime events/messages.  Currently looking for a way for my 3.2.14 legacy app to have a more "realtime" feel.

Comment: @MarcoCI is right on -- websockets is the best way to solve. PubNub and similar third party services work really well. I'm not sure what in Rails4 would solve your problem.

Comment: You don't have to upgrade to Rails 4.x.x: just use a WebSocket (such Socket.IO or SockJS) implementation and that's it.

Comment: @MarcoCI Is there a good tutorial on how to integrate Socket.IO into Rails 3.2.x that you could recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use new feature :

```
ActionController::Live
```

his module was developed by Aaron Patterson to enable data to be streamed live from Server to Client. Essentially, instead of returning html or JSON as a response to an html request,  ActionController::Live enables an i/o stream to be returned as a response. This means we can define an action in a controller that will set up a stream of live data to any client that requests it, until the connection is closed again.

```
class SensorController < ApplicationController

 include ActionController::Live

 def temperature

   response.headers['Content-Type'] = ‘text/event-stream’

   100.times {

     response.stream.write(“The temperature is #{ 100*rand} degrees Celcius\n”)

     sleep 0.5

   }

   response.stream.write(“That’s all for now!”)

 ensure

   response.stream.close

 end

end
```

You may find at this link: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live/SSE.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating AJAX requests every 10 seconds, you can use websockets combined with a Redis pubsub mechanism to dynamically update your Rails partials.  Here's a gem that can help you out with refreshing the divs in realtime:

https://github.com/llawlor/meteorite